# Serverless: SQLAlchemy hangs on session.commit()

Tags: python, python-3.x, orm, sqlalchemy, serverless-framework

I'm writing a serverless application using SQLAlchemy.

This is my code

```
def create_mysql_engine():
    db_endpoint = os.environ['DB_ENDPOINT']
    db_username = os.environ['DB_USERNAME']
    db_password = os.environ['DB_PASSWORD']

    return create_engine('mysql+pymysql://' + db_username + ":" + db_password
                         + '@' + db_endpoint + ':3306/mydb')

mysql_engine = create_mysql_engine()
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind = mysql_engine)
session = DBSession()
session.add(new_user)
session.commit()
```

On the `commit()` statement, it stucks. I'm not able to figure out why.

Comment: Please can you describe how "it stucks", do you see some error or does it freeze ?

Comment: I'm using AWS serverless. So the task gets killed after 300 seconds.